# Mouse thinks it is in a different tmux pane

Tags: tmux

I am using tmux 3.0 in bash over ssh on CentOS 7. My tmux.conf is fairly simple. It has some bindings and

```
set-option -g mouse on
set -g focus-events on
```

I have a fairly large tmux window with 3 vertical panes. When I move the mouse to the right side of the rightmost pane and do something (e.g. scroll with mouse wheel or click to select this pane). The action gets executed on the leftmost pane instead.

This behavior persists if I detach from and reattach to the session. Any ideas what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: I'd try the same without `focus-events` to see if it behaves the same or not. `focus-events` shouldn't affect the basic mouse functionality in panes. It might focus you on what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal emulators which do not support SGR mouse mode will not correctly report any mouse actions to the right of column 227. Is your terminal emulator window wider than this?

Try using a different terminal emulator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info Nicholas! I just counted the columns when it is starting to happen. The first column it happens is exactly column 256 (0-based). I am using "GNOME Terminal 2.31.3". Is there some option I need to set on it. If not, what is a good terminal for CentOS 6?

Comment: I just tried xterm and it does not appear to have this problem!

Comment: You could try a newer gnome-terminal because IIRC it should support this, perhaps your version is too old. You will also need to update VTE which is the widget it uses. There are lots of other terminals but I don't know which ones work on CentOS 6.

Comment: The old mouse sequence can only represent bytes 0-255 and some terminals don't use 0-31, so it will either be column 256 or 225 where it fails not 227. But if you find one that supports SGR mouse mode then there is no limit you are likely to reach.